# Reverse Polish Notation in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, arithmetic-expressions, rpn

I need to write a function that takes an arithmetic expression and converts it to a string in Reverse Polish notation using Haskell. Creating a function to evaluate an RPN expression is quite easy and need not to worry about, it's only the conversion from arithmetic to RPN that's troubling.

Comment: To parse infix arithmetic you need to implement [operator precedence](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2326328/414413).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [parsec](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsec) for parsing the string. It's powerful and enables you to implement robust parsing. You can then build a data structure out of the input string which you then pass to your RPN logic.